# Text box / select advanced option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I want users to be able to type text into the text box I set up.
If they do not know their options, I want them to be able to click **expand** and select from a drop-down menu, such as on [this](http://www.tigerair.com/sg/en/) page.

How can I get this?

Comment: Cleaned up grammar and expression.

Answer (score 0):

- For HTML only solution use [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist):

```html
<input list="somelist" name="myBrowser" />
<datalist id="somelist">
  <option value="option1">
  <option value="option2">
  <option value="option3">
</datalist>
```

- For a bit more custom solution you can use jQuery UI's [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)
- To get more options you can use [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: This will provide auto complete but I want a window to open and allow a user to see these options also.

Comment: The options can be seen by clicking on the right side of the textbox. In Chrome you can see an arrow also, though I believe its the only browser that implemented this element with a side arrow. Anyway I added another solution.

Comment: Thanks. Could I use 2 methods. Method 1: Use DataList as in your code example and Method 2: being a DIV which is displayed on focus of the textbox and use JavaScript to add the text into the textbox from clicking it on the displayed DIV?